# calling Python Script from c++ using shell command

Tags: c++, python-2.7, shell, ubuntu, embed

I want to call my Python script named as Test.py from c++ program and print output in myoutput.txt file by using command shell in c++ code.
I run script through ubuntu terminal by running below commands:

```
 $ python Test.py > myoutput.txt
```

and save results in myoutput.txt file successfully....But when i run this command through Shell command then no output is write in the myoutput.txt file... below is the way where i execute the command

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    std::string filename = "/home/madeeha/Test.py > myoutput.txt";
    std::string command = "python ";
    command += filename;
    system(command.c_str());
}
```

and my python Script Test.py is below:

```
# Import model
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import pickle

df = pd.read_csv('/home/madeeha/Final_DataSet.csv')
tf = df
final_tf = pd.DataFrame(tf)
tf = df
final_tf = pd.DataFrame(tf)
# Create features variable, x
x_train = final_tf[['LocalLoadHigh', 'LocalLoadLow', 'TransitLoadHigh',
    'TransitLoadLow','phaseTotalBlocking', 'phaseTotalLocalBlocking', 'phaseTotalTransitBlocking', 'PBlockingLocalHigh',
    'PBlockingLocalLow', 'PBlockingTransitHigh', 'PBlockingTransitLow',
    'UtilizationHigh', 'UtilizationLow']]
# Create target variable, y
y_train = final_tf['WavelengthGroup']
# Create linear regression object
lm = LinearRegression()
model = lm.fit(x_train,y_train)

#    save the model to disk
filename = 'finalized_model.sav'
pickle.dump(model, open(filename, 'wb'))
df = pd.read_csv('/home/madeeha/workspace/IBKSIM/OneRowRegressionFiles/15_s1packetscheduler0.csv')
tf = df
final_tf = pd.DataFrame(tf)
    # Create features variable, x
x_test = final_tf[['LocalLoadHigh', 'LocalLoadLow', 'TransitLoadHigh',
    'TransitLoadLow','phaseTotalBlocking', 'phaseTotalLocalBlocking', 'phaseTotalTransitBlocking', 'PBlockingLocalHigh',
    'PBlockingLocalLow', 'PBlockingTransitHigh', 'PBlockingTransitLow',
    'UtilizationHigh', 'UtilizationLow']]
    # load the model from disk
loaded_model = pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
predictions = loaded_model.predict(x_test)
print(predictions)
```

Comment: Just to make sure: You don't, be any chance, want to write to `/home/madeeha/myoutput.txt`, rather than the current directory `/myoutput.txt` are you?

Comment: no issue of directory...it can be written anywhere...after that i will give the pah of myoutput.txt to c++ program by reading the txt file

Comment: Can you share the python script Test.py ? I tried the same scenario in my pc where python script prints "hello there" and it is working fine. I think there is something wrong in the python file.

Comment: i am stuck at this point and not finding any error...you can give any .csv file to it and apply linear regression,....

Comment: i have also tried through this way #include <Python.h>, then Py_Initialize() to start your python interpreter. but it also runs simple python print function and not running my script......